# Is it possible to have two front end modules in the same app? If so, how?

Tags: reactjs, gradle, frontend, multi-module

### Preface

I have a gradle project, Bookstore, and the project directory looks a bit like this:

```
Bookstore
 - bs-application
 - bs-config
 - bs-controller
 - ...
 - bs-frontend
 - gradle
```

Recently, we've decided that we want to temporarily integrate a `/admin` route, controlled by another module so it can be cleanly removed when the time comes -- It will also make use of a lot of extra libraries & packages for newer front-end development.

The project directory now looks like this: (everything kept separate)

```
Bookstore
 - bs-application
 - bs-config
 - bs-controller
 - ...
 - bs-frontend
 - gradle
 - admin-config
 - admin-controller
 - admin-sal
 - admin-frontend
```

### Possibly helpful extra information

In `bs-frontend`, I have my `Bookstore.js` that is essentially,

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
    <Route exact path='/login' component={Login}/>
    <Route exact path='/about' component={About}/>
    ...
    ...
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

### My question

Both are react-based & when a user hits `/admin` I would like them to see what is built under the `admin-frontend` module. If this were permanent, I'd just build an `Admin` component within `bs-frontend`, make another route, and be done with it -- but I can't do that here. **How do I integrate these apps together?**

I'm not sure exactly what information to give because I'm not sure what is helpful, so please let me know if/what I can add to be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood hereby, `bs-frontend` and `admin-frontend` are two different application and want to share component between them.
In that case we have 2 different options.

1. **publish as package**: you can publish `admin` component as npm package can consume as a node_module in `bs-frontend`(I believe u have npm private registry in ur org).
   **or**
2. you can try with webpack 5 feature called **"Module Federation"**, which will expose component and can consume in ur `bs-frontend` app.